# appication.view is not getting import in django urls

Tags: python, django

i have been making a django project using pycharm community edition i did install application in settings.py it is not getting import in django urls.py

```
from productapp.Views import Home
```

productapp is my app name and this is query ive writen  in django.urls file expecting it  to get import in my urls file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.